# Is it problematic to have a mixed environment (Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 and MonoDevelop)?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, macos, monodevelop, virtual-machine

I've just join a team of .NET developers on a .NET project where I will basically do the front-end HTML and CSS (LESS).

They run Windows and Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 and I run Mac OS X with a Windows VM in order to also run Microsoft Visual Studio 2010.

I was wondering if I could simply get rid of my Windows virtual machine and install MonoDevelop and use it on my Mac in order to code my HTML and CSS on this project without causing any problems.

Will it build the solution correctly. Is there a list of known issues. Because I don't want to mess things up.

Many thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *should* build the Visual Studio 2010 solutions just fine. If it doesn't, then it's a bug and we would appreciate getting a bug report about it so that we can fix it!

I've been going back and forth between Visual Studio and Xamarin Studio while working on one of my personal side projects at home and have had no problems at all. Normally I just use Xamarin Studio on my MacBook Air, but for long hacking periods, I prefer to work at a desktop, and at home, I have a Windows PC for my desktop and figured I'd try and get to know Visual Studio 2010 a bit better so I can try to bring the better features back over to XS.

Comment: Thank you @jstedfast for your response. Will test for sure.